# Publish an update just for new users Android Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, backend, app-update

I would like to publish some update of my app on the Play Store, however since I will just change the default setting given at the beginning when a user install the app for the first time, I would like that these updates are not seen by current users (that would have to update the app for nothing). Is there a way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that.

In future consider using some service which will provide a configuration for your app remotely (such as Firebase).